# Best practices to display own dynamic images using imageview in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android Application in which this application is divided into 3 vertical layouts.

1 . I have an `ImageView` in the third layout to display dynamic images , one image at a time inside this `ImageView`.

2 . Dynamic images are retrieved from remote server.

What is the best approach to handle above case.

Shall I download the images to local sdcard or use one of the android imageurl librarie?

Answer (score 2):

I would recomment to use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). It is widely used and handles caching and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use one of those libraries:

- [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
- [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
- [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)

They handle performance, caching, memory usage, customizations...